# Creating custom event out of window.onhashchange functionality, for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, delegates

I thought it will be better to rephrase the whole question after gathering some information on how to resolve my problem.

The simple question now is how to create a custom event out of `window.onhashchange` functionality.

I wanted to do this because as you may know you cannot attach handler on javascript loaded content, you will be able to solve this by

`$('parent').on('event', 'child', func)` right?  which is equivalent to jquery delegate functionality.

How can I create a custom event out of `window.onhashchange`

Comment: The question is kind of hard to read. What do you want to happen? What isn't happening? What does the browser tell you when it isn't happening?

Comment: Uhmm last part of my question will be able to tell you what I am saying, thanks

Comment: i'm gonna edit the question, all of it. Bec. I think I have a better way to ask it after researching

Answer (score 0):

Ohhhh. Okay. Well, window is the only thing that it makes sense for hashchange to trigger on so I'm not sure why you would want event delegation. Listen to the window. When there is a hash change, do what you want to whatever HTML currently exists.

You actually can attach handlers to JavaScript-appended content. If it's in the DOM, it's something you can manipulate and listen for events on. The problem is when you replace the html content. The original dom node is gone so if for instance you had a click event, it's registered to a node that no longer exists.

But window can only be replaced by reloading the page and that's the only thing a hash change should be relevant to. Also 'hashchange' isn't a real DOM event. If it made sense for it to trigger on an element I'm not sure it would still bubble like an event like 'click' does.

Short version: I'm not sure you're having the problem you think you're having if you need something to happen on this 'hashchange' event.

Comment: you are right that the html is replaced, but I wanted that the replaced content could handle the hashchange event, makes sense?

Comment: The hashchange event isn't triggered on the content. It's triggered on the window. The handler is the function that should fire when a hashchange event is triggered on the window. Change whatever HTML you want with the handler function.